# How to collect admin phrases?

Tags: magento2, csv, importexport, translate, language-package

I am using i18n:collect-phrases command but seems that it collects only frontend phrases.

I need to collect only admin panel phrases!

For example, I have downloaded some language pack, but it does not fully translate the admin panel.

Is there any way to collect custom language pack admin panel phrases together with untranslated phrases so I could translate untranslated phrases manually and after import it back?

If it's not possible then I really would be grateful for possibility collect only admin panel phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it is possible.
The format should be like this:

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases [-o|--output="<csv file path and name>"] [-m|--magento] <path to directory to translate>
```

A working sample command looks like this:

```
php bin\magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\i18n\en_US.csv" C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\adminhtml
```